# SQL query rewrite for prettification and or performance improvement

Tags: sql

I have a query that essentially amounts to:

```
  Select query 1
Union
  Select query 2
  where rowid not in query 1 rowids
```

Is there a prettier / more performant way to do this?  I'm assuming the results of query 1 would be cached and thus utilized in the union... but it's also kinda oogly.

Update with the original query:

```
    SELECT FruitType
    , count(CASE WHEN Status = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Fresh
    , count(CASE WHEN Status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Ripe
    , count(CASE WHEN Status = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Moldy
    FROM FruitTypes FT1
    LEfT  JOIN Fruits F on F.FTID = FT1.ID
    where 
      Fruit.IsHighPriced = 0
    GROUP BY FruitType
Union ALL
    select FruitType, 0 as Fresh, 0 as Ripe, 0 as Moldy
    FROM FruitTypes ft3
    where 
      ft3.StoreID = @PassedInStoreID
    and FruitType NOT IN 
    (
        SELECT FruitType
        , count(CASE WHEN Status = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Fresh
        , count(CASE WHEN Status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Ripe
        , count(CASE WHEN Status = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Moldy
        FROM FruitTypes FT2
        LEfT  JOIN Fruits F on F.FTID = FT2.ID
        where 
          Fruit.IsHighPriced = 0
        GROUP BY FruitType
    )
```

Thanks!

Comment: Based on what you say, the only unreasonable part of the query is `union` instead of `union all`.  If you provide more information, there may be other strategies.

Comment: Never try to pretify sql. The best performing SQL statements are often ugly. In databases performance is critical and taking an extra tem nimutes to figure out what id does is far less important than taking extra time every one of the thousands (or millions) of times it runs.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's quite that simple @HLGEM. Making something prettier to look at can be really helpful to both yourself and others in the future, but you should just restrict your prettification attempts to whitespace and casing... both of which are pretty random in the OPs code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the second case statement in the NOT in clause.   And not Exists is often faster in SQL Server.

```
 SELECT FruitType
        , count(CASE WHEN Status = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Fresh
        , count(CASE WHEN Status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Ripe
        , count(CASE WHEN Status = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Moldy
        FROM FruitTypes FT1
        LEfT  JOIN Fruits F on F.FTID = FT1.ID
        where 
          Fruit.IsHighPriced = 0
        GROUP BY FruitType
    Union ALL
        select FruitType, 0 as Fresh, 0 as Ripe, 0 as Moldy
        FROM FruitTypes ft3
        where 
          ft3.StoreID = @PassedInStoreID
        and NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT *
            FROM FruitTypes FT2
            LEfT  JOIN Fruits F on F.FTID = FT2.ID
            where 
              Fruit.IsHighPriced = 0
              and ft3.FruitType = FT2.FruitType
                   )
```

Answer (score -1):

The prettiest way of writing would probably be by turning query #1 into a view or a function, then using that view or function to call the repetitious code.

Performance could possibly be improved by using query #1 to fill a temp table or table variable, then using that temp table in place of the repititious code.